# Make loop with matrix slice more efficient

Tags: python, performance

I want to make the code below more efficient, but I'm not sure how. I want to use numpy and native python libraries only.

```
iterations = 100
aggregation = 0
for i in range(iterations):
    aggregation += np.sum(np.linalg.norm(dat[dat_filter==i] - dat_points[i], axis=1))
```

dat is a nxD matrix
dat_filter is a vector of length n containing an identifier from 0 to num_iterations
dat_points is num_iterators x D matrix.

Basically I am computing distances between a matrix Dat whose points belong to a class versus the points of that class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't very easy to vectorize the problem since you have square roots of parts of your data that are not nescesarilly the same length. You could vectorize parts of it for a small speed up:

```
import numpy as np

# Make some data
n = 200000
d = 100
iterations = 2000

np.random.seed(42)
dat = np.random.random((n, d))
dat_filter = np.random.randint(0, n_it, size=n)
dat_points = np.random.random((n_it, d))


def slow(dat, dat_filter, dat_points, iterations):
    aggregation = 0
    for i in range(iterations):
        # Wrote linalg.norm as standard numpy operations,
        # such that numba can be used on the code as well
        aggregation += np.sum(np.sqrt(np.sum((dat[dat_filter==i] - dat_points[i])**2, axis=1)))
    return aggregation

def fast(dat, dat_filter, dat_points, iterations):
    # Rearrange the arrays such that the correct operations are done
    sort_idx = np.argsort(dat_filter)
    filtered_dat_squared_sum = np.sum((dat - dat_points[dat_filter])**2, axis=1)[sort_idx]
    # Count the number of different 'iterations'
    counts = np.unique(dat_filter, return_counts=True)[1]
    aggregation = 0 
    idx = 0 
    for c in counts:
        aggregation += np.sum(np.sqrt(filtered_dat_squared_sum[idx:idx+c]))
        idx += c
    return aggregation
```

timings:

```
In [1]: %timeit slow(dat, dat_filter, dat_points, n_it)       
3.47 s ± 314 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [2]: %timeit fast(dat, dat_filter, dat_points, n_it)     
846 ms ± 81.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Using numba with the `slow` function speeds it up slightly, but still not as fast as the `fast` method. Numba with the `fast` function makes the call slower on the matrix sizes I tested.

Comment: Superb! That's really helpful. Thanks!